# Keyboard hook freezes hooked app

Tags: delphi, winapi, hook

Using a typical WH_KEYBOARD hook to catch keystrokes. It worked fine in WinXP but has issues with Win7+ - **if the control app sleeps or hangs, it also hangs the hooked window, even if Postmessage is used**. Is it a known issue? I need to make the message handler async from the hooked window.... (Currently is makes other apps to freeze and wait if my app is making some heavy actions). When I log the dll to txt file, I do not see any hangs in KeyboardProc..

hook lib

```
library myHook

...

function KeyboardProc(Code : Integer; wParam : WPARAM; lParam : LPARAM): LRESULT; stdcall;
const
  SysKeys: set of Byte = [8, 9, 13, 27];
var
  KeyDown: Boolean;
  KeyChar: WideChar;
  rslt: LongBool;
  ta: integer;
begin
  if Code = HC_ACTION then
  begin
    KeyDown := (lParam and (1 shl 31)) = 0;
    if KeyDown then
    begin

      if not (wParam in SysKeys) and GetKeyboardState(Keyboard) then
        begin
          kl := GetKeyboardLayout(GetWindowThreadProcessId(GetForegroundWindow, nil));
          ta := ToUnicodeEx(wParam, (lParam and $00FF0000) shr 16, @Keyboard, @KeyChar, 1, 0, kl);

        end
      else
        ta := 0;

      if ta = 1 then
        rslt := PostMessage(DestHandle, WM_KEYHOOK, SourceHandle, Ord(KeyChar))
      else
        rslt := PostMessage(DestHandle, WM_EXKEYHOOK, SourceHandle, lParam);
    end;
  end;
  Result := CallNextHookEx(KeyboardHook, Code, wParam, lParam);
end;

function StartListen: Boolean; export stdcall;
begin
  try
    KeyboardHook := SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD, @KeyboardProc, HInstance, 0);
    Result := True;
  except
    Result := False;
  end;
end;

function StopListen: Boolean; export stdcall;
begin
  if KeyboardHook > 0 then UnhookWindowsHookEx(KeyboardHook);
  Result := True;
end;

....
exports
  StartListen, StopListen;

begin
  DestHandle := FindWindow(shcHookWndClass, nil);
end;
```

my class to launch hook and receive messages

```
constructor TSysHook.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited;
  FWindowHandle := CreateInVisibleWindow(shcHookWndClass, HookProc);
end;

procedure TSysHook.HookProc(var Msg: TMessage);   //if we make a break point here - hooked window hangs!
begin
  case Msg.Msg of
      WM_KEYHOOK:        DoOnKeyDown(Msg);     
      WM_EXKEYHOOK:      DoOnExKeyDown(Msg);
    else
      Msg.Result := DefWindowProc(FWindowHandle, Msg.Msg, Msg.WParam,
        Msg.LParam);
  end;
end;
...
```

Comment: From [KeyboardProc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644984.aspx): *"This hook may be called in the context of the thread that installed it. The call is made by sending a message to the thread that installed the hook. **Therefore, the thread that installed the hook must have a message loop.**"*

Comment: Your StartListen's return should depend on the result of SetWindowsHookEx, SetWindowsHookEx will not raise anything.

Comment: thread that installed the hook is a vcl forms application and of course it all works fine with processing the messages. the problem appears if we make a sleep for example or some heavy load is created...   so, this cannot be resolved with main thread and I should create a separate thread that has no other load except hook msg proc ?

Comment: @AlexanderM. Sounds reasonable. Create thread for the hook that runs its own message loop, independently from the main application. You must also create a **message queue**, for instance by calling `PeekMessage()` **on this thread**. See remarks under [PostThreadMessage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644946(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: making a message queue with   while not Terminated and GetMessage(msg, 0, 0, 0) do    DispatchMessage(msg);  in that thread...  but now the problem is how to send an event to the main thread without syncing that may hang the thread again... :)

Comment: I've used PostMessage from HookProc listener Thread to the main thread's window - and still same result:))) if main thread hangs, all the chain hangs...  why??

Comment: Did you specify the thread ID in the call to `SetWindowsHookEx()`?

Comment: What is your ultimate goal with this code?

Comment: "Did you specify the thread ID in the call to SetWindowsHookEx()" - tried, and it does not catch anything then...   I've understood that the main problem is that in XP hookproc was workin in the hooked process context and in Win7+ hookproc works in the calling process context....  So, I can export hookproc to a separate process and use PostMessage to main process to avoid lags chain. Correct?

Comment: "What is your ultimate goal with this code?" - capture keystrokes from all apps. (User behavior analysis software)